# How to use Html.Partial() inside of custom html-helper in ASP.NET MVC 5?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, html-helper

I want to create a custom separated from page html-helper that would use partial views functionality, but for some reason `Html.Partial("_partialName")` doesn't work

Content of separated cshtml file in `App_Code`:

```
@helper MyHelper(IEnumerable<string> something)
{
    <div>@Html.Partial("_viewName", something)</div>   
}
```

How to just use `Html.Partial` like in Razor view page?

Comment: Define "doesn't work" please

Comment: @Andrei My bad. Here is the error text "HtmlHelper doesn't contains definition for Partial, most suitable method PartialExtensions.Partial(HtmlHelper, string)". I know what it about, tryed several ways to use this extension method, but with no results :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't just call `Html.Partial("_name", model);` in a helper method. `Partial` is an extention method to `HtmlHelper` type and `Html` is a property of View (which inherits from `WebViewPage<TModel>`). You can check it by going to the view (or partial view) and navigating to the definition of `Html`.

Calling it from a helper does not make sense, thus it does not have an object which exposes an accessible property `Html` form `WebViewPage<TModel>` type. In fact it is an instance of `CustomHtml` class. Try writing `@this.` in both view and helper. You'll see how they are different.

Comment: I came to the same conclusions recently and deside to make an extension method to HtmlHelper that provides an Instance of itself.